# Printing a vector in C++ - why must the vector be passed as a constant or as a copy?

Tags: c++, function, vector

I have been playing around with vectors and writing my own function that prints their elements. This function is straightforward to code, but I noticed a small detail which I cannot explain.

Say I have the following function that prints the elements (I'm only shown the declaration here)

```
void print(vector<int> vec);
```

And that I have another function that creates and returns a vector:

```
vector<int> create_vector( //parameters);
```

And lastly, say in my main function I wanted to run something along the lines of

```
print(create_vector(// some paramters));
```

I noticed this works. What also works is if I pass my vector into my `print` function as a constant reference:

```
void print(const vector<int>& vec);
```

However, what does not work is if I simply pass it by reference

```
void print(vector<int>& vec);
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::vector&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::vector’
```

I would think this is because I am trying to print a variable that has not yet been realized, but if that's the case how come it works when passed as a constant reference?

Comment: `create_vector(...)` returns an rvalue (a temporary vector); `void print(vector<int>& vec);` is the signature of a function that is expected to change the passed vector.  However if you could pass a temporary (rvalue) then any changes would be thrown away at the end of the full expression (the `;`) when the temporary vector is deleted.  Thus the compiler is helping you not make a mistake.

Comment: A `const&` reference can bind to a temporary.  A `&` reference cannot.  A `&&` reference can bind a temporary.  Which one you need to use depends on your functions contract.

Comment: @Eljay So in effect ``const&`` creates a temporary instance of the function which is what allows you to use the print function, whereas simply passing by reference does not?

Comment: Ahem, your question has nothing to do with printing or vectors, it is much more general: It's passing an object returned to another function as parameter.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you, I wasn't sure how to categorize my problem but putting it under functions makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Both create a temporary, but C++ prevents you from using a mutating reference `&` from modifying a temporary that is about to go away.  Under the assumption that any mutations to the referenced parameter are intended to serve some greater purpose... so a reference to a temporary is probably a bug.

Comment: FYI: Search for "[c++]" plus the error message, which should already give you many hits.

Comment: Your question is understood, but can you show the actual code? This signature 'void foo(std::vector<int>& v)' shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just to make my previous comment clear, you have to pass a non-constant reference to that function. Your create_vector() returns an rvalue not a reference. If you changed the print() function signature to take an rvalue reference (std::vector<int> &&) it will work with your create_vector() function.